Building a bidirectional index jump for the question-answering environment
I am not proficient in English, and the following text is partially translated by Google.
My purpose is:

Construct a pair of problem-result environments, and use a pair of \question-\answer control sequences in the corresponding environment to number each question/answer;
Give a label to each number, and let the numbered text of each pair of question-answer jump to each other according to the correct label.

Current problem: The first goal has been achieved, but the second one has encountered difficulties. Clicking the numbered text does not jump to the correct place.
According to my own test, the problem may be that the label is not correctly recognized.
% XeLaTeX
% Cn & En mixed typesetting
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newenvironment{practice}[1]
   {\newline\vskip .3cm\centering \large\textbf{Practice}\setcounter{question}{0}%
    \vskip .1cm\flushleft\normalsize%
    \def\thisname{#1}
  }
   {\vskip .3cm}

\newcounter{result}
\setcounter{result}{1}
\newenvironment{result}[1]
   {\setcounter{answer}{0}%
   \vskip .1cm\flushleft\normalsize%
   \def\thisname{#1}}
   {\vskip .5em\refstepcounter{result}}

\renewcommand*{\theresult}{\arabic{result}}

\newcounter{question}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labelquestion}[1]{%
   \stepcounter{question}%
   \label{#1Question\arabic{question}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\question}{\indent\labelquestion{\thisname}\hyperref[{\thisname Answer\arabic{question}}]{\textbf{\thesubsection.\thequestion}\hskip .2cm}}

\newcounter{answer}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labelanswer}[1]{%
   \stepcounter{answer}%
   \label{#1Answer\arabic{answer}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\answer}{\par\indent\labelanswer{\thisname}\hyperref[{\thisname Question\arabic{answer}}]{\textbf{\theresult.\theanswer.}}\hskip .2cm}

\begin{document}
\section{Practices}
\subsection{Here is CatA}
    blablabla
    \begin{practice}{CatA}
        \question Question 11\\
        \question Question 21\\
        \question Question 31\\
    \end{practice}
    \newpage
\subsection{Here is CatB}
    blablabla
    \begin{practice}{CatB}
        \question Question 12\\
        \question Question 22\\
        \question Question 32\\
    \end{practice}
    \newpage
\subsection{Here is CatC}
    blablabla
    \begin{practice}{CatC}
        \question Question 13\\
        \question Question 23\\
        \question Question 33\\
    \end{practice}
    \newpage
    \section{Results}
    \begin{result}{CatA}
        \answer Answers 11\\
        \answer Answers 21\\
        \answer Answers 31\\
    \end{result}
    \newpage\ 
    \newpage
    \begin{result}{CatB}
        \answer Answers 12\\
        \answer Answers 22\\
        \answer Answers 32\\
    \end{result}
    \newpage\ 
    \newpage\
    \begin{result}{CatC}
        \answer Answers 13\\
        \answer Answers 23\\
        \answer Answers 33\\
    \end{result}
\end{document}


You should use \refstepcounter for counters that you want to reference. With hyperref this also sets the anchor for links.
For correct links you also must ensure that \theH<counter> is unique across a document.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{practice}
\newenvironment{practice}[1]
   {\newline\vskip .3cm\centering \large\textbf{Practice}\stepcounter{practice}\setcounter{question}{0}%
    \vskip .1cm\flushleft\normalsize%
    \def\thisname{#1}
  }
   {\vskip .3cm}

\newcounter{result}
\setcounter{result}{1}
\newenvironment{result}[1]
   {\setcounter{answer}{0}%
   \vskip .1cm\flushleft\normalsize%
   \def\thisname{#1}}
   {\vskip .5em\refstepcounter{result}}

\renewcommand*{\theresult}{\arabic{result}}

\newcounter{question}
\renewcommand\theHquestion{\thepractice.\thequestion}
\newcommand{\labelquestion}[1]{%
   \refstepcounter{question}%
   \label{#1Question\arabic{question}}}
\newcommand{\question}{\indent\labelquestion{\thisname}\hyperref[{\thisname Answer\arabic{question}}]{\textbf{\thesubsection.\thequestion}\hskip .2cm}}

\newcounter{answer}
\renewcommand\theHanswer{\theresult.\theanswer}
\newcommand{\labelanswer}[1]{%
   \refstepcounter{answer}%
   \label{#1Answer\arabic{answer}}}
\newcommand{\answer}{\par\indent\labelanswer{\thisname}\hyperref[{\thisname Question\arabic{answer}}]{\textbf{\theresult.\theanswer.}}\hskip .2cm}

\begin{document}
\section{Practices}
\subsection{Here is CatA}
    blablabla
    \begin{practice}{CatA}
        \question Question 11\\
        \question Question 21\\
        \question Question 31\\
    \end{practice}
    \newpage
\subsection{Here is CatB}
    blablabla
    \begin{practice}{CatB}
        \question Question 12\\
        \question Question 22\\
        \question Question 32\\
    \end{practice}
    \newpage
\subsection{Here is CatC}
    blablabla
    \begin{practice}{CatC}
        \question Question 13\\
        \question Question 23\\
        \question Question 33\\
    \end{practice}
    \newpage
    \section{Results}
    \begin{result}{CatA}
        \answer Answers 11\\
        \answer Answers 21\\
        \answer Answers 31\\
    \end{result}
    \newpage\ 
    \newpage
    \begin{result}{CatB}
        \answer Answers 12\\
        \answer Answers 22\\
        \answer Answers 32\\
    \end{result}
    \newpage\ 
    \newpage\
    \begin{result}{CatC}
        \answer Answers 13\\
        \answer Answers 23\\
        \answer Answers 33\\
    \end{result}
\end{document}

